# Listing files on a remote server and retrieving those having not been modified since 10 minutes

Tags: bash, ssh

I am attempting to retrive files on remote server by use of bash / ssh / scp.
I need to retrieve only files having not been modified since more than 10mn.
Once retrieved, I am checking there are in local folder, and if yes, I remove them on remote server.

To do so, I started with this bash script... that is not working.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

S_ACCOUNTS=('me')
RMT_IP='112.17.58.322'
LOC_PATH_DATA='../data/cs_remote'
MOD_TIME='+10'                    # Last modification time, in minutes



# List, copy, delete files.
for serv_account in "${S_ACCOUNTS[@]}"; do
    mkdir -p "$LOC_PATH_DATA""$serv_account"
    filels="( $(ssh root@$RMT_IP ls -Q "/root/test/*.txt") )"
    for filename in $filels; do
       # Only copy if file has not been modified since 10 minutes.
        if test `ssh root@$RMT_IP find "$filename" -mmin "$MOD_TIME"`; then
            scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa root@$RMT_IP:"$filename" "$LOC_PATH_DATA""$serv_account"
            if test -f '"$LOC_PATH_DATA""$serv_account"/$(basename "$filename")'; then
                echo "$(basename "$filename") successfully copied."
                ssh root@$RMT_IP "rm $filename"
            fi
        fi
    done
done
```

I have difficulty with testing file has not been modified since more than 10mn, and get following error message:

```
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `-mmin'
bash: -c: line 0: `find ( -mmin +10'
protocol error: filename does not match request
protocol error: filename does not match request
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
bash: -c: line 0: `find ) -mmin +10'
```

Would you have any idea on how issuing this `find` command over `ssh`?

Thanks for your help.
Have a good day, bests,

Comment: There is how to fill array by files names: `files=() ; while read f ; do files+=("$f") ; done < <( IFS=$'\n' ls )` And there is how to loop through them: `for f in "${files[@]}" ; do echo "$f" ; done`

Comment: Hi @Albelisto, thanks for the tip. Fortunately, I have no trouble with the loop. As indicated by the title, this is the 'find' command that fails. There is no whitespace in filenames.

Comment: Still I am trying to understand what you have written. Please, what does mean '<( IFS=$'\n' ls )'? Thanks for the tip.

Comment: `bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token '-mmin' bash: -c: line 0: 'find ( -mmin +10'` - it is trouble with the loop. `<( ... )` - use command as a "virtual" file, for example `grep b <( ls -l / )` `IFS=$'\n' ls` - set separator for following command only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired from @Abelisto comment, I finally wrote:

```sh
for serv_account in "${S_ACCOUNTS[@]}"; do
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
        printf "Copying file $COUNT, ""$(basename "$file")"".\n"
        scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa root@$RMT_IP:"$file" "$LOC_PATH_DATA""$serv_account"
        if test -f "$LOC_PATH_DATA""$serv_account"'/'"$(basename "$file")"; then
            printf 'Removing '"$(basename "$file")"'.\n'
            ssh root@$RMT_IP -n "rm $file"
        fi
    done < <(ssh root@$RMT_IP "find "/root/$serv_account/data" -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +1k -mmin $MOD_TIME -print0")
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will fail if you have space in the filename of any file

Because the name of the file with spaces will split and you will get the name in few line instead in full name.

```sh
filels="( $(ssh root@$RMT_IP ls -Q "/root/test/*.txt") )"
    
for filename in $filels; do
    ...
```

for example

```sh
$ ls 
 file.log  'some file.txt'

$ for i in $(ls -Q); do; echo $i; done
"file.log"
"some
file.txt"
```

Comment: Hi @m_g, thanks for the tip. Fortunately, I have no trouble with the loop. As indicated by the title, this is the 'find' command that fails. There is no whitespace in filenames.